# SQL submitting 0 instead of actual value. Also dropping @ and . in email address

Tags: php, mysql, forms, submit

The below code is what I am using to submit my form data. The form submits just fine and redirects without issue.

When I look at the row data within the database, I notice that companyname, firstname, and lastname are being inserted as 0's. I also noticed that, while the email address is being inserted into the database, it is dropping the @ and . from the address.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
include("inc/conf.inc.php"); // Includes the db and form info.
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { // If the form has not been submitted.

} else { // The form has been submitted.
    $companyname = form($_POST['companyname']);
    $firstname = form($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = form($_POST['lastname']);
    $username = form($_POST['emailaddress']);
    $password1 = md5($_POST['password1']); // Encrypts the password.
    $password2 = md5($_POST['password2']);

    if (($companyname == "") || ($firstname == "") || ($lastname == "") || ($username == "") || ($password1 == "") || ($password2 == "")) { // Checks for blanks.
        exit("There was a field missing, please correct the form.");
    }

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE emailaddress = '$username'") or die (mysql_error()); // mySQL Query
    $r = mysql_num_rows($q); // Checks to see if anything is in the db.

    if ($r > 0) { // If there are users with the same username/email.
        exit("That email address is already in use!");
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (companyname,firstname,lastname,emailaddress,password) VALUES ('$companyname','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password1')") or die (mysql_error()); // Inserts the user.
    header("Location: thankyou.php"); // Back to login.
    }
}
mysql_close($db_connect); // Closes the connection.
?>




   <?php
$db_user = ""; // Username
$db_pass = ""; // Password
$db_database = ""; // Database Name
$db_host = "localhost"; // Server Hostname
$db_connect = mysql_connect ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass); // Connects to the database.
$db_select = mysql_select_db ($db_database); // Selects the database.

function form($data) { // Prevents SQL Injection
   global $db_connect;
   $data = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/', '', $data);
   $data = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($data), $db_connect);
   return stripslashes($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the `form` function look like?

Comment: The `form()` function is doing something odd, like possibly casting a string to an integer (which results in 0 for non-numeric strings)

Comment: I can see some potential for SQL injections as well, you might want to take a look at http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: You should really use PDO and prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Some other notes: password will NEVER be empty and md5('') will still return a value. [Not to mention that md5 is not strong enough to encrypt a password for a serious project]. Also you don't compare password1 and password2 are the same.

Comment: @doublesharp but you might be wrong because you have no idea what form() function does. Maybe it looks like to `function form($val){ return mysql_real_escape_string($val); }`...

Comment: @Robbie md5 isn't strong enuf if you do return the string from this one only one time, like `$str = md5($str)` but it becomes much stronger if you do return the string twice, like `$str = md5(md5($str))` This is because there are databases with md5 hashes. If you hash the string properly with md5 there's no need to use much stronger algs. like sha1() ...

Comment: @Geoff_Montee I do believe that this one much better for beginners: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @metal_fan agreed, but given the lack of knowledge about the `form()` function, I see potential SQL injection issues. `$password1` and/or `$password2` might also be null if the query value is null. Checking for `empty()` might be better than checking for an empty string.

Comment: I swear sometimes I feel stupid using this site....posting above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any help would be appreciated

So let me start from this :)
I'm sorry, but
Your code is extremely unorganized...

Let's assume that your new config(or lib) file will be similar to this one:

File: `config.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 * @param string $host Mysql host
 * @param string $user Mysql username
 * @param string $passw Mysql password
 * @param string $db Mysql database to work with 
 * @return TRUE if could connect and select given database
 */
function connect($host ='ur host', $user='ur username', $passw='ur passw', $db='ur dbname'){
  if ( !mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $passw) ){
     die("Can't connect to SQL server");
   }

  if ( mysql_select_db($db) ){
   die("Can't select database");
  }

 return true;
}

/**
 * Determine whether user has been registered before
 * @param string $email
 * @return boolean
 */
function userAlreadyExists($username){
   if ( connect() ) { //ensure we are connected
      #Prevent injection right here:
      $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); 

      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE emailaddress = '$username' LIMIT 1");

      if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
         # True means that user exists
         return true;
       } else {
         #False means that user do not exists: 
        return false;
       }
   }

  /**
   * 
   * @return boolean
   * TRUE if could insert new row
   * FALSE if this row already exists or error in sql server
   */
  function addNewUser($companyname, $firstname, $lastname, $username, $password1){

  $companyname = mysql_real_escape_string($companyname);
  $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
  $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password1 = md5($password1);

    if ( connect() ){
      return mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`   (`companyname`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`emailaddress`,`password`) VALUES ('$companyname','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password1')");

   }

  }

  /**
   * Function that compare password that makes sure
   * if they're the same
   */
  function pass_compare($pass1, $pass2){

    if ($pass1 !== $pass2){
       die("Passwords are not the same");
    }
    return true;
  }
```

File `handler.php`

```
<?php

if ( !empty($_POST) ){ //This code runs when form has been submitted 

 //Maybe we should check if some value is missing, before we connect SQL //server!? 

  #Check if some field is missing:
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $val){

    if ( empty($key) ){
      sprintf('The field %s is missing', $key);
       die();
    }
  }

  #connect mysql server
  connect();

  if (userAlreadyExists($_POST['email'])){

    die(printf('The <b>%s</b> is already in use', $_POST['email']));

  } else {

   if ( pass_compare($_POST['password'], $_POST['password_confirm']) ){  

   addNewUser($_POST['companyname'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    }
  }


}
```

This will work for you

Comment: I just realized looking at my DB....those columns were set to INT and not VARCHAR

Comment: Fixed the INT issue. Those columns populate correctly now on submission.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice, the fields you mentioned are processed by the function form(). You might want to print them to check the return values from form() function.

Also, instead of the check,

```
  ($companyname == "")
```

use :

```
  empty($companyname)
```

It checks for more things than just empty string.

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)